# Automatically creating worksheets based on a list in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to achieve the following.

When I enter a value on 'Master' worksheet in the Range A5:A50, a macro is run which creates a new worksheet with the same name as the value and then copies the template onto the new sheet.

In addition to this I would also like to copy the value adjacent to the value enter on Master worksheet to this new worksheet so it does calculations automatically.

For example I enter '1' in A5 and '2' in B5. I would like to create a new worksheet with name '1', copy the template from 'Template' worksheet and copy the value of B5 on to the new worksheet named '1'.

I have following code but it also tries to copy Template worksheet with macro is run which results in an error because a worksheet with name 'Template' already exists.

```
Sub CreateAndNameWorksheets()
    Dim c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In Sheets("Master").Range("A5:A50")
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        With c
            ActiveSheet.Name = .Value
            .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                "'" & .Text & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=.Text
        End With
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Copy the template? are you trying to create new template with  different name?

Comment: re: *'and copy the value of B5 on to the new worksheet named '1'.'* Copy it where on the new worksheet?

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click the Master worksheet's name tab and select *View Code*. When the VBE opens up, paste the following into the window titled something like *Book1 - Master (Code)*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(target, Rows("5:50"), Columns("A:B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Dim r As Long, rw As Long, w As Long
        For r = 1 To Intersect(target, Rows("5:50"), Columns("A:B")).Rows.Count
            rw = Intersect(target, Rows("5:50"), Columns("A:B")).Rows(r).Row
            If Application.CountA(Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 2)) = 2 Then
                For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
                    If LCase(Worksheets(w).Name) = LCase(Cells(rw, 1).Value2) Then Exit For
                Next w
                If w > Worksheets.Count Then
                    Worksheets("Template").Visible = True
                    Worksheets("Template").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                    With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                        .Name = Cells(rw, 1).Value2
                        .Cells(1, 1) = Cells(rw, 2).Value
                    End With
                End If
                With Cells(rw, 1)
                    .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(rw, 1), Address:="", _
                        SubAddress:="'" & .Value2 & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=.Value2
                End With
            End If
        Next r
        Me.Activate
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Worksheets("Template").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Me.Activate
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that this depends on you having a worksheet named **Template** in order to generate the new worksheets. It also keeps the Template worksheet xlVeryHidden which means that it will not show up if you try to unhide it. Go into the VBE and use the Properties window (e.g. F4) to set the visibility to visible.

This routine should survive pasting multiple values into A2:B50 but it will discard proposed worksheet names in column A that already exists. There must be a value i both column A and column B of any row before it will proceed.

There are currently no checks for illegal worksheet name characters. You may want to familiarize yourself with those and add some error checking.

Comment: Thought up a better method of ensuring single operation when both A and B receive values at once. Modified above.

Comment: @Jeeped thank you so much for your detailed response. I will try this out and update you. You have definitely put in a lot of effort and highly appreciate that. Thank you once again. Unfortunately the Excel on Mac is a little different and it is not showing me 'View Code' option when clicking on sheet name at the bottom. Will try it out on Windows Excel in office and update you.

Comment: @Jeeped Can you please take this a step further? Suppose I need calculations done on the master sheet based on data from the newly created sheets. Essentially a formula like ='NewSheet'!A1 in column 3 of the master sheet. (Should I start new question?)

Comment: Actually, just thought of an idea I might try but confident your architecture will be superior so please feel free to make inputs.

Comment: This code uses `With Cells(rw, 1)` to identify the cell in column A to put a hyperlink into. It should be a small matter to use `Cells(rw, 3).Formula = "='New Sheet'!A1"` .

Answer (score 0):

Another example relevant to the post title but not the specific application. Code updates sheets in master list with list row number creating sheet from template if it doesn't exist.

Other reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18411820/9410024.

```
Sub UpdateTemplateSheets()
    ' Update sheets in list created from a template
    ' 
    ' Input: List on master sheet, template sheet
    ' Output: Updated sheet from template for each item in list
    '
    Dim wsInitial As Worksheet
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim lVisibility As XlSheetVisibility
    Dim strSheetName As String
    Dim rIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long

    On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ' Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set wsInitial = ActiveSheet
    Set wsMaster = Sheets("Summary")
    Set wsTemp = Sheets("Template")

    lVisibility = wsTemp.Visible          ' In case template sheet is hidden
    wsTemp.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    For rIndex = 2 To wsMaster.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' Ensure valid sheet name
        strSheetName = wsMaster.Cells(rIndex, "A").Text
        For i = 1 To 7
            strSheetName = Replace(strSheetName, Mid(":\/?*[]", i, 1), " ")
        Next i
        strSheetName = Trim(Left(WorksheetFunction.Trim(strSheetName), 31))

        ' Ensure sheet name doesn't already exist
        If Not Evaluate("IsRef('" & strSheetName & "'!A1)") Then
            wsTemp.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                .Name = strSheetName
            End With
        End If
        With Sheets(strSheetName)
            .Range("B59").Value = rIndex * 16 + 1        ' Update template block option row
        End With
    Next rIndex

Safe_Exit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    wsInitial.Activate
    wsTemp.Visible = lVisibility  ' Set template sheet to its original visible state

End Sub
```